# Adding geom_ribbon in a loop plots only the last Figure of the loop and gives an error in R

Tags: r, for-loop

```
For (i in 1:3){

#…Here I determine the following as data.frame: 1) mean_values, 2) Time, 3) medians, 4) stages, 5) quantiles_mean_values, 6) quantiles_medians…

    pdf(file="test.pdf", height=9)
    If (i==1){
        One<-ggplot(mean_values,aes(x=Time,y=mean_values)) +
        geom_line(linetype='dashed')+
        scale_y_log10()+
        geom_line(data = medians, aes(x = Time, y = median), color="blue")+
        geom_point(data = stages, aes(x = Time, y =stages ))+         
        geom_ribbon(data=quantiles_mean_values,aes(ymin=X25.,ymax=X75.), alpha=0.4,fill="orange")+
        geom_ribbon(data=quantiles_medians,aes(ymin=X25., ymax=X75.),alpha=0.2,fill="blue")
    }
    if (i==2) { 
        Two<-ggplot(mean_values,aes(x=Time,y=mean_values)) + 
        geom_line(linetype='dashed')+ 
        scale_y_log10()+
        geom_line(data = medians, aes(x = Time, y = median), color="blue")+
        geom_point(data = stages, aes(x = Time, y =stages ))+
        geom_ribbon(data=quantiles_mean_values,aes(ymin=X25., ymax=X75.), alpha=0.4,fill="orange")+
        geom_ribbon(data=quantiles_medians,aes(ymin=X25., ymax=X75.), alpha=0.2,fill="blue")
    }
    if (i==3){
        Three<-ggplot(mean_values,aes(x=Time,y=mean_values)) +
        geom_line(linetype='dashed')+
        scale_y_log10()+
        geom_line(data = medians, aes(x = Time, y = median),color="blue")+
        geom_point(data = stages, aes(x = Time, y =stages ))+
        geom_ribbon(data=quantiles_mean_values,aes(ymin=X25.,ymax=X75.),alpha=0.4,fill="orange")+
        geom_ribbon(data=quantiles_medians,aes(ymin=X25., ymax=X75.),alpha=0.2,fill="blue")
    }
} 
grid.arrange(One, Two, Three, ncol=3,nrow=3)
dev.off()
```

When I comment out the `geom_ribbon(..)` everything works perfectly fine. Including the `geom_ribbon(...)` allows me to only plot the last Figure, i.e. Three, and gives me an error for the other two, namely

> Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the data Problems:X25., X75

If I only consider for (i in 1:2) it will again only plot the last figure, i.e. Two, and give me the same error for the first plot. If I just for (i in 1:1), it will give me the Figure One with no error. Overall, it seems that the plots One, Two, Three interact with each other inside the loop, although they should not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to better help us help you please take some time to format your question more clearly including code so we can reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to ask this question:

The for loop for the ggplot works fine until you add the

> > geom_ribbon(...)

code in there. Any chance that this happens because the for loop does not know where to draw the data for the geom_ribbon?

## Can you generate some random data using this a code like that so we can run it and figure it out?

> > matrix(rbinom(10*1000, 1, .5), ncol=(#put the number you want here))